# Getting no iad requests and impressions

Tags: iphone, iad

I've just released my first iPhone app three days ago and I still can't see any iAd ads on it. I just wanted to know how many downloads I need in order to get ad requests in the iad.apple.com website

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate iAd review that your app is put into after it comes on the app store. I had to wait about a week for advertisements to actually start popping up.

Comment: But we will come up eventually? Does it matter how many downloads I get per day even if it's a little amount? Because I saw on iad.apple.com that I have 400 requests but that's it! No impressions